Discord WSS connection closed after one heartbeat
In my DotNet project, when connecting to the discord gateway (api v10) it connects fine, and responds with:
{"t":null,"s":null,"op":10,"d":{"heartbeat_interval":41250,"_trace":["[\"gateway-prd-us-east1-b-dg02\",{\"micros\":0.0}]"]}}.
So I wait 41250 ms (or whatever it happens to be) and when i then send the heartbeat:
{ op = 1, d = null }
It closes the connection with no further info.
How do I fix this?
(Initial payload)

